# Datasource issue in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, datasource

Hello everyone I wanted to create datasource dynamically from cfm file. Datasource is creating successfully with no issue but its (created datasource) status is not OK. Below the code that I'm using to create datasource:

```
<cfscript>
    adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator"); 
    isLogin = adminObj.login("#form.filed_6#");
    myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.datasource");
    myObj.setMSSQL(driver="MYSQL5",
    name="#form.filed_4#", host = "#irongate.hostname#", port = "3306",
    database = "xyz",username = "#irongate.username#", password="#irongate.password#",
    timeout = "20", interval = 7, buffer = "64000", blob_buffer = "64000", 
    setStringParameterAsUnicode = "false",description = "", pooling = true, 
    maxpooledstatements = 1000, enableMaxConnections = "true",
    maxConnections = "300", enable_clob = true, enable_blob = true, 
    disable = false, storedProc = true,
    alter = false, grant = true, select = true, update = true, create = true, 
    delete = true, drop = false,
    revoke = false);
 </cfscript>
```

I'm using MYSQL5 Driver.
Note:  Datasource created with no errors but when I submit the datasource in ColdFusion administration then the following error generates.
[image: Error Screenshot]

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: ColdFusion appends `;jdbcbehavior=0` to the connection string which is rejected by the MySQL JDBC driver due to being invalid syntax. As far as I can see, ColdFusion does this based on the detected driver, so there might be an issue with the JDBC driver you added to `cfusion/lib` (since MySQL doesn't ship any longer with newer ColdFusion versions). What version of the MySQL JDBC are you using? Another possible reason: You are passing an unsupported param when creating the datasource, which cannot be used with MySQL. Try creating a working DS with as few params as possible and add one by one.

Comment: Hi @Alex,
JDBC driver version is 8.0.25.

`(rejected by the MySQL JDBC driver due to being invalid syntax)`   
so how to eliminate the invalid syntax from coding?

`(Try creating a working DS with as few params as possible and add one by one)`
Yeah firstly I was passing a very few params only insert, update, delete etc. But the same issue was occuring.

`Note:` I'm not getting when you say JDBC driver issue. When I creating datasource from administrator, it works fine with mysql 5 driver. However when I create it from code then it is not perfect as it should be(But its created BTW).

Comment: Is there any reason why you're taking this approach instead of defining it in Application.cfc?

Comment: Datasources are crarting dynamically for multipler servers to access one centralized server database. So instead of going to each server application file and edit their file by placing one by one script, an installation script will be added to other servers.

Comment: @AdamCameron Do you have one example of creating dynamic datasource in cfc file instead?

Comment: As a matter of fact I do! https://blog.adamcameron.me/2022/09/cfml-working-mysql-datasource-in.html

Comment: @AdamCameron thanks for sharing such helpful material. I have a query. Where I need to add database also host? it is just asking me for username and password.
I have to create datasource for other server database.

Comment: `this.datasources["dsn1"] = {
            driver = "mysql5",
            class = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            url = "jdbc:mysql://HOST_HERE:3306/"
                & "DATABASE_HERE"
                & "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
            username = 'USERNAME_HERE',
            password = 'PASSWORD_HERE'
        }
        this.datasource = "dsn1"`

I'm using above piece of code but it is not creating a datasource in my ColdFusion administration.

Comment: Yer thinking about it the wrong way round: the object of the exercise is to have a data source, not to have a data source _in CFAdmin_. The data source UI in CFAdmin is just that... a UI for creating data sources. If you can do it in your application code, you don't need the admin UI.